# How to resolve error while saving to a folder in VBA in Mac

Tags: excel, vba

```
Public Function SaveForMac()
    Dim WS As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim SaveToDirectory As String

    Dim CurrentWorkbook As String
    Dim CurrentFormat As Long

    Dim mUsername As String
    mUsername = GetUserNameMac()

    CurrentWorkbook = ThisWorkbook.FullName
    CurrentFormat = ThisWorkbook.FileFormat
    ' Store current details for the workbook
    SaveToDirectory = "/Users/" & mUsername & "/Downloads/"
    For Each WS In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        Sheets(WS.Name).Copy
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=SaveToDirectory & ThisWorkbook.Name & "-" & WS.Name & ".csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV
        ActiveWorkbook.Close savechanges:=False
        ThisWorkbook.Activate
    Next

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ThisWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=CurrentWorkbook, FileFormat:=CurrentFormat
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    ' Temporarily turn alerts off to prevent the user being prompted
    '  about overwriting the original file.
End Function

Function GetUserNameMac() As String
    Dim sMyScript As String

    sMyScript = "set userName to short user name of (system info)" & vbNewLine & "return userName"

    GetUserNameMac = MacScript(sMyScript)
End Function
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Run-time error '1004':

Application-defined or object-defined error
```

For this line:

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=SaveToDirectory & ThisWorkbook.Name & "-" & WS.Name & ".csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV
```

How can i resolve this so it saves correctly in the Downloads folder.

Comment: Does `Debug.Print SaveToDirectory & ThisWorkbook.Name & "-" & WS.Name & ".csv"` return what you expect?

Comment: Yes it does return what I expect. I even `Command` + `Shift` + `G` and entered the `SaveToDirectory` path and it worked.

Comment: I haven't tried it but would changing the `/` to ``\`` work for the path name?

Comment: Replace `Sheets(WS.Name).Copy` with `WS.Copy`  and  `ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs` with `WS.SaveAs`

Comment: @GMalc THAT WORKED!!!!! Thank you thank you!!!

Comment: Weird the edited code worked yesterday but doesn't work today and I get the same error :/